# Perform an action after an entry's button is pressed in SwiftEntryKit

Tags: swift

I have added 2 buttons to my [SwiftEntryKit](https://github.com/huri000/SwiftEntryKit) popup but cannot figure out how to do something after a button is pressed.

I follow the pattern set with [their example for alerts](https://github.com/huri000/SwiftEntryKit/blob/04c7fa33490d5c52572aeb308c6df638e8d723e7/Example/SwiftEntryKit/Presets/PresetsViewController.swift).

I tried entering something into the dismiss action, but it did not work:

```
// Ok Button
let okButtonLabelStyle = EKProperty.LabelStyle(font: buttonFont, color: buttonColor)
let okButtonLabel = EKProperty.LabelContent(text: "OK, ACCEPT", style: okButtonLabelStyle)
let okButton = EKProperty.ButtonContent(label: okButtonLabel, backgroundColor: .clear, highlightedBackgroundColor:  buttonColor.withAlphaComponent(0.05)) {
    SwiftEntryKit.dismiss {
        print("okButton")
    }

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set `entryInteraction` to `.absorbTouches` for the `attributes` property of `SwiftEntryKit.display`.

```
var attributes = EKAttributes()
attributes.entryInteraction = .absorbTouches

[...]

SwiftEntryKit.display(entry: <entry variable>, using: attributes)
```